# Test class problem for a batch class

Tags: unit-test, batch, class

I have a test class for a batch class that I can't get above 82% coverage. There is one part of the batch class that the test does not go into. I think it should be but it isn't. Any help is appreciated.

Batch class

```
public class BatchInvestigatorLastMonthSurvey  implements Database.Batchable<SObject> 
{
   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)

    {
        //query on Provider
        String query = 'Select Id,Last_Month_Quality_Surveys__c from Contact ';
        system.debug('return');
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List <Contact> spUpdate)
    {
         // Create LastMonthKey*******************************************************************************************
      // *****************************************************************************************************************
                       date myDate = date.today();
                     date lastDate = myDate.addMonths(-1);
                 Integer lastMonth = lastDate.Month();
                 Integer lastYear  = lastDate.Year();
               String lastMonthkey = string.valueof(lastMonth) + string.valueof(lastYear);   
      //************************************************************************************************************************


       Map<id,Contact>contactMap = new Map<id,Contact>(); 


       AggregateResult[] groupedResults =[Select count(id) noOfPro, provider__c from Survey_response__c where New_Quality_survey__c = true
                                           and Study__r.Master_Agreement_Study__c=True
                                            and Month_Year_Key__c =: lastMonthKey 
                                           and Study_Provider__r.Provider_Status__c != 'Terminated'
                                           group by provider__c ] ;  


       for(aggregateResult ar:groupedResults){

           Contact vStudyPro = new Contact();

           string accId=(string) ar.get('provider__c') ;
                decimal countofchild =(decimal)ar.get('noOfPro');
                vStudyPro=new Contact(id=accId,Last_Month_quality_surveys__c =countofchild);
                system.debug('Study Pro Id = '+ ar.get('provider__c'))  ;
                system.debug('Count of Surveys = '+ ar.get('noOfPro'));
                spUpdate.add(vStudyPro);

        }


    for (Contact studyProv:[Select Id, RecordTypeID
                  from  Contact
                  where RecordTypeId in (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Clinic')  
                            and Last_Month_Quality_Surveys__c != 0     
                            and Id not IN:spUpdate     ]){

        Contact theRest = new Contact();
        string restId=(string) studyProv.get('Id');
         decimal zeroz=0;                               
         theRest=new Contact(id=restId, Last_Month_quality_surveys__c = zeroz);                                 
        spUpdate.add(theRest);
                                     }

            for (Contact con:spUpdate){
            contactMap.put(con.Id,con);
        }                                 

            update contactMap.values(); 

        }



    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    }
}
```

and here is the test class:

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=false)
public with sharing class TestBatchInvestigatorLastQS{

    static testMethod void InvestigatorRecordTest() {

        Date todaysCurrentDate =date.today();
        date afterDrop= Date.newInstance(2016,12,02);
        date dropped = date.newInstance(2016,12,01);
        date beforedrop = date.newInstance(2016,11,05);
        date lastDate = todaysCurrentDate.addMonths(-1);

      string aStudy = 'a00A000000dIV3nIAG';

        List<RecordType> recordTypeList = [ SELECT ID, DeveloperName, Name, SobjectType FROM RecordType ];
        ID clinicRTid, patienRTid, accClinicRTid, pharmacyRTid;
        Id agreeFixFeeRTId, agreePPSurveyRTId;  // Agreement Record Types 
        Id agreeRuleFixFeeRTId, agreeRulePPSurveyRTId;  // Agreement Rule Record Types
        Id studyPartRTId, targetPartID;

        // Pick up the Record Type Id's for each of the Records we're going to create and test 
        for( RecordType aType : recordTypeList ) {
            if( aType.DeveloperName == 'Clinic' && aType.SobjectType == 'Contact' ) {
                clinicRTid = aType.ID;
            }
            if( aType.DeveloperName == 'Clinic' && aType.SobjectType == 'Account' ) {
                accClinicRTid = aType.ID;}
          if( aType.DeveloperName == 'Patient' && aType.SobjectType == 'Contact' ) {
          patienRTid = aType.ID;
            }

            if( aType.DeveloperName == 'Pharmacy' && aType.SobjectType == 'Account' ) {
                pharmacyRTid = aType.ID;
            }


            if( aType.DeveloperName == 'OPERA_Study_Participant' && aType.SobjectType == 'Study_Participant__c' ) {
                studyPartRTId = aType.ID;
            }   
            if(aType.DeveloperName == 'TARGET_Study_Participant' && aType.SobjectType == 'Study_Participant__c'){
                targetPartID =aType.ID;
            }

        }

        // create accounts
        Account anAcct = new Account();
        anAcct.Name = 'SGI Test';
        anAcct.RecordTypeID=accClinicRTid;
        anAcct.Account_Status__c='Active';
        anAcct.BillingCountryCode='US';
        anAcct.BillingStateCode='NY';
        anAcct.ShippingCountryCode='US';
        anAcct.Shipping_State__c='NY';
        insert anAcct;

        // create Pharmacy account
        Account aPharmacy = new Account();
        aPharmacy.Name = 'SGI Pharmacy Test';
        aPharmacy.RecordTypeID = pharmacyRTid;
         aPharmacy.BillingCountryCode='US';
       aPharmacy.BillingStateCode='NY';
       aPharmacy.ShippingCountryCode='US';
        aPharmacy.Shipping_State__c='NY';
        insert aPharmacy;

        // create Participant contact
        Contact pContact = new Contact();
        pContact.FirstName = 'T';
        pContact.LastName = 'C';
        pContact.RecordTypeID = patienRTid;
        pContact.Birthdate= date.newinstance(1977,12,01);
        pContact.Provider_Code__c = '52345';
        pContact.MailingCountryCode='US';
        pContact.MailingStateCode='NY';
        insert pContact;

        // create contact
        Contact aContact = new Contact();
        aContact.FirstName = 'Test';
        aContact.LastName = 'Contact';
        aContact.RecordTypeID = clinicRTid;
        aContact.Provider_Code__c = '12345';
       aContact.Date_Current_Agmt_Signed__c = todaysCurrentDate.addMonths(-3);
       aContact.Payment_Account__c = anAcct.Id;
        aContact.Provider_Clinic__c = anAcct.ID;
        aContact.Pharmacy__c = aPharmacy.ID;
        aContact.MailingCountryCode='US';
        aContact.MailingStateCode='NY';

        insert aContact;
     // system.debug(aContact);


        //system.debug(addContact);

        // create study
        Study__c bStudy = new Study__c();
        bStudy.Name = 'TARGET';
        bStudy.Minimum_Study_Age__c = 10;
        bStudy.Maximum_Study_Age__c = 90;
        bStudy.Start_Date__c = beforedrop;
        bStudy.Study_Prefix__c = 223;
        bStudy.Max_Study_Code__c = 54321;
        insert bStudy;


     //create study provider
        Study_Provider__c aProvider = new Study_Provider__c();
        aProvider.Provider__c = aContact.ID;
        aProvider.Provider_Clinic__c = anAcct.ID;
        aProvider.Pharmacy__c = aPharmacy.ID;
        aProvider.Provider_Status__c = 'Active';
        aProvider.Study__c = aStudy;
        aProvider.Study_Code__c = '123456';
      //  aProvider.Last_Month_Quality_Surveys__c = 20;
        aProvider.Payment_Account__c = anAcct.Id;

        insert aProvider;

       Survey__c s = new Survey__c();
        s.Name = 'Test Survey';
        s.Comments__c = 'Test Comments';
        s.Survey_Status__c ='Active';
        s.Survey_Amount__c = 10;
        s.Study__c=aStudy;
        s.Unqualified_Amount__c = 0;
        s.BaseLine_Survey__c=False; 
        insert s;

        Survey__c s2 = new Survey__c();
        s2.Name = 'Test Survey';
        s2.Comments__c = 'Test Comments';
        s2.Survey_Status__c ='Active';
        s2.Survey_Amount__c = 10;
        s2.Study__c=bStudy.id;
        s2.Unqualified_Amount__c = 0;
        s2.BaseLine_Survey__c=False;    
        insert s2;

    // Create Study Participant before CSE
        Study_Participant__c studyP = new Study_Participant__c();

        studyP.Name = 'Test Study Participant';
        studyP.HIPAA_Forms_Received__c=True;
        studyP.Patient_Authorization_Form__c =TRUE;
       // studyP.CSE_Forms_Received__c = TRUE;
        studyP.Participant__c= pContact.Id;
        studyP.Study_Provider__c=aProvider.Id;
        studyP.Provider__c = aContact.ID;
        studyP.Study__c = aStudy;
        studyP.Participant_Status__c = 'Active';
        studyP.RX_in_Florence__c = True;
        studyP.RecordTypeId = studyPartRTId;  
       // studyP.Date_of_Dropout__c = dropped;
        studyP.PK_Key__c='1659702884';

        insert studyP;


        // Create Study Participant after CSE
        Study_Participant__c studyP2 = new Study_Participant__c();

        studyP2.Name = 'After Study Participant';
        studyP2.HIPAA_Forms_Received__c=True;
        studyP2.Patient_Authorization_Form__c =TRUE;
        studyP2.CSE_Forms_Received__c = TRUE;
        studyP2.Participant__c= pContact.Id;
        studyP2.Study_Provider__c=aProvider.Id;
        studyP2.Provider__c = aContact.ID;
        studyP2.RX_in_Florence__c = True;
        studyP2.Study__c = bStudy.id;
        studyP2.Participant_Status__c = 'Active';
        studyP2.Insurance_Status__c = 'Covered';
        studyP2.RecordTypeId =  targetPartID;  
        studyP2.PK_Key__c='1659702884';     
        insert studyP2;

 Prescription__c Perp = new Prescription__c ();
        Perp.Study__c = aStudy; 
        Perp.Drug__c = 'Test Drugg'; 
        //Perp.NPI_PK__c = vNPI;
       // Perp.Participant_code__c = zName;
        Perp.Insurance__c = 'I';
        Perp.Study_Provider__c = aProvider.id;
        Perp.Study_Participant__c = studyP.id;
        Perp.Provider__c= aContact.id;
        Perp.Patient__c=pContact.id;
        Perp.Fill_Date__c = afterDrop;

        insert Perp;        

        //beforedrop and before CSE // New_Quality_Survey__c == True

        Survey_Response__c survey2 = new Survey_Response__c();

            survey2.Name='Test Survey Responses 1';
            survey2.Study__c = aStudy;
            survey2.Study_Participant__c = studyP.Id;
            survey2.Study_Provider__c=aProvider.Id;
            survey2.Survey__c=s.Id;
            survey2.Valid_Study_Participant__c = true;
            survey2.New_Quality_Survey__c=True;
            survey2.Source__c = 'eFax';
            survey2.Participant__c = pContact.Id;
            survey2.Payment_Status__c='New';
            survey2.Date_Time_Received__c = lastDate;
            survey2.Date_Taken__c=lastDate;
            survey2.Provider__c= aContact.Id;
            insert survey2;

        //no drop and after CSE //New_Quality_Survey__c = True
      Survey_Response__c survey6 = new Survey_Response__c();

            survey6.Name='Test Survey Responses 1';
            survey6.Study__c = bStudy.id;
            survey6.Study_Participant__c = studyP2.Id;
            survey6.Study_Provider__c=aProvider.Id;
            survey6.Survey__c=s2.Id;
            survey6.Valid_Study_Participant__c = true;
            survey6.Source__c = 'eFax';
            survey6.Participant__c = pContact.Id;
            survey6.Payment_Status__c='New';
            survey6.New_Quality_Survey__c=True;
            survey6.Date_Time_Received__c = lastDate;
            survey6.Date_Taken__c=lastDate;
            survey6.Provider__c= aContact.Id;
            insert survey6;  



      List<Survey_Response__c> surveyList = new List<Survey_Response__c>();
        Survey_Response__c survey5 = new Survey_Response__c();

         // Baseline received after droppedout // New_Quality_Survey__c ==False
        For (Integer i=0;i < 40;i++ ){
        survey5 = new Survey_Response__c();

            survey5.Name='Survey Response'+string.valueof(i);
            survey5.Study__c = aStudy;
            survey5.Study_Participant__c = studyP.Id;
            survey5.Study_Provider__c=aProvider.Id;
            survey5.Survey__c=s.Id;
            survey5.New_Quality_Survey__c=True;
            survey5.Valid_Study_Participant__c = true;
            survey5.Source__c = 'eFax';
            survey5.Participant__c = pContact.Id;
            survey5.Payment_Status__c='New';
            survey5.Date_Time_Received__c = lastDate;
            survey5.Date_Taken__c=lastDate;
            survey5.Provider__c= aContact.Id;
            surveyList.add(survey5);
        }
        insert surveyList;
       survey_response__c updateSurvey5 =[Select id, Quality_Survey_Override__c, Baseline_survey__c, Dropout_Date__c, New_Quality_Survey__c, Study__c, Study_Participant__r.Dropout_Date__c, 
                                          Study_Provider__r.Provider_Status__c from Survey_Response__c where id=:Survey5.id];
         update updateSurvey5;

        //the 'Not Quality' Override Survey // New_Quality_Survey__c ==False
        Survey_Response__c survey = new Survey_Response__c();
            survey.Name='Quality Test 2';
            survey.Study__c = aStudy;
            survey.Study_Participant__c = studyP.Id;
            survey.Study_Provider__c=aProvider.Id;
            survey.Survey__c=s.Id;
            survey.Valid_Study_Participant__c = true;
            survey.Source__c = 'eFax';
            survey.Participant__c = pContact.Id;
            survey.Payment_Status__c='New';
            survey.Date_Time_Received__c = lastDate;
            survey.Provider__c= aContact.Id;
            survey.Quality_Survey_Override__c = 'Not Quality';        
            insert survey;

        //the 'Quality' override Survey // New_Quality_Survey__c == True
        Survey_Response__c survey3 = new Survey_Response__c();
            survey3.Name='Quality Test 2';
            survey3.Study__c = aStudy;

            survey3.Study_Participant__c = studyP.Id;
            survey3.Study_Provider__c=aProvider.Id;
            survey3.Survey__c=s.Id;
            survey3.Valid_Study_Participant__c = true;
            survey3.Source__c = 'eFax';
            survey3.Participant__c = pContact.Id;
            survey3.Payment_Status__c='New';
            survey3.Date_Time_Received__c = lastDate;
            survey3.Provider__c= aContact.Id;
            survey3.Quality_Survey_Override__c = 'Quality';    
            insert survey3;


       contact addContact = new Contact();
        addContact.RecordTypeID = clinicRTid;
        addContact.FirstName='No';
        addContact.LastName='Study';
        addContact.Last_month_quality_surveys__c = 12;
        addContact.Provider_Code__c='33333';
        addContact.MailingCountryCode='US';
        addContact.MailingStateCode='NY';
        addContact.AccountId = anAcct.id;
        insert addContact;

    contact again = new Contact();
     again.RecordTypeID = clinicRTid;
        again.FirstName='Try';
        again.LastName='Again';
        again.Last_Month_Quality_Surveys__c= 0;
        again.Provider_Code__c ='43234';
        again.MailingCountryCode='US';
        again.MailingStateCode='TX';
        again.AccountId=anAcct.id;
        insert again;


        Test.startTest();


        contact UpdateaddContact=[Select Id, recordtypeid,last_month_quality_surveys__c from Contact where id=:addContact.id];
        update UpdateaddContact;

        contact testAgain=[Select Id, recordtypeid,Last_month_quality_surveys__c from Contact where id =:again.id];
        update testAgain;

        study_participant__c updateStudyP =[Select id, Date_enrolled__c, Dropout_Date__c, CSE_Forms_Received__c, Participant_Insurance_Status__c, RX_in_Florence__c from Study_Participant__c where id=:StudyP.id]; 
                    system.debug('StudyP= '+ updateStudyP);

         study_participant__c updateStudyP2 =[Select id, Date_enrolled__c, Dropout_Date__c, Participant_Insurance_Status__c, CSE_Forms_Received__c , RX_in_Florence__c from Study_Participant__c where id=:StudyP2.id]; 
                    system.debug('StudyP2= '+ updateStudyP2);


       BatchInvestigatorLastMonthSurvey myBatchObject1 = new BatchInvestigatorLastMonthSurvey();
        Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject1);



       Test.stopTest();

       Contact validateProviders = [select id, last_month_quality_surveys__c from contact  where id=:aContact.Id];
       update validateProviders;
      System.assertEquals(41,validateProviders.last_month_quality_surveys__c );   
      system.debug('last month qs for aContact = '+validateProviders.Last_month_quality_surveys__c);

      Contact testContactUp = [Select Id, recordtypeid, Last_month_quality_surveys__c from Contact  where id=:addContact.id];
       update testContactUp;  
       system.debug('Last Month # addContact '+testContactUp.last_month_Quality_Surveys__c) ;
       system.assertEquals(0,testContactUp.Last_Month_Quality_Surveys__c) ;

      contact testAgain2=[Select Id, recordtypeid,Last_month_quality_surveys__c from Contact where id =:again.id];
       system.assertEquals(0,testAgain2.Last_Month_Quality_Surveys__c) ;




    }

    }
```

Comment: If you indicate the lines that are not covered in your question that would make it easier for people to focus on the problem.

Comment: This is the part with the problem. Contact theRest = new Contact();
        string restId=(string) studyProv.get('Id');
         decimal zeroz=0;                               
         theRest=new Contact(id=restId, Last_Month_quality_surveys__c = zeroz);                                 
        spUpdate.add(theRest);

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, please invoke "execute" method:

```
Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject1);
myBatchObject1.execute(null, new List<Contact>{yourContactsHere});
```

The same approach with "finish" method if needed.

Comment: I believe that will cause an error. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes I am using this approach very often. Please note that I have updated batch instance name from "batch" to "myBatchObject1" used in the question , now is clear I hope.

Comment: Invoking `Database.executeBatch` between a `Test.startTest();` and `Test.stopTest();` will run the start/execute/finish cycle for one batch so is a good way to go for most batchables.

Comment: the above looks like it will invoke the `execute()` method twice

Answer (score 0):

Create contact test data with the below record types. make sure the for loop SOQL where criteria is met.

```
Map <String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeMap = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();

Contact contactObj = new Contact();
if(recordTypeMap.containsKey('Clinic')) 
{
 contactObj.RecordTypeId = recordTypeMap.get('Clinic').getRecordTypeId();
}
```

I think you need to make the below change too

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `start()` method return all contacts as there is no where condition. So `spUpdate` list in `execute()` will get all contacts returned from start(). In execute you were checking **Id not IN : spUpdate** in below for loop.

```
for (Contact studyProv:[Select Id, RecordTypeID
                  from  Contact
                  where RecordTypeId in (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Clinic')  
                  and Last_Month_Quality_Surveys__c != 0     
                  and Id not IN : spUpdate ])
```

Ideally there will be no contact because all the contacts you created is there in `spUpdate`. That's why code inside this for loop is not covered.

So please check your conditions while execute soql. Let me know your comments.